# Sass: placeholder behaviour for selectors

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm having some trouble understanding the placeholder behavior for selectors when compiled into css. So I've created a placeholder inside a class selector (.test) and I'm trying to extend it into another class (.test1) inside a third class (.test2). it compiled into css without any error although I'm curious how the selectors formed when compiled. here are the output and code snippets.

This is not actual use case but I'm just wondering how the selectors formed in the output?

```
.test {
  %placeholder {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.test2 {
  .test1 {
    @extend %placeholder;
  }
}
```

### Output

```
.test .test2 .test1, .test2 .test .test1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, but what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @George I was wondering how the selectors are formed.